# Default identity pages is displayed on Azure published site

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-web-app-service

I published my web site to an Azure App service (http://quickpic.azurewebsites.net)
Unfortunately the default identity pages keeps on displaying even though I have changed all of its styling and added fields to it.

My current result is 
https://www.quickpic.co.za/TestSite/default.png

My expected result that i get in debugging is
https://www.quickpic.co.za/TestSite/expected.png

Comment: Looks like your Deploy (Publish) went wrong.

Comment: There's not enough information here to properly diagnose the issue. However, my best guess is that you haven't set up minification properly for your custom CSS, so something like `site.min.css` doesn't actually exist on the deployed site. For Development, you're referencing `site.css`, so there's no issue, but in Production, you're referencing `site.min.css`, which doesn't exist, and therefore no styling is being applied.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank you i have looked into that but that isn't the case, none of my html or css is being loaded and I don't have a .min.css file to load. Is there any other information that I can supply you guys with?

Comment: Yes do tell us: is it a proper MVC site (or Razor pages, the default)? Did you scaffold the Identity pages?

Comment: @HenkHolterman have been busy the last while, yes it is a proper MVC site with controllers and razor views. I have been looking to see if I find more identity dll's or something but not coming up with anything

Comment: Well, I couldn't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We upgraded the project to .Net Core 3.0 and published to azure and that seems to have fixed our problems.